# Trying to match line with regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match the following line:

```
801. Our origination charge (Includes Originat ion Point (s) %  or $ ) (f rom GFE #1)$ 1,169.00
```

I have created this regular expression:

`.*801\..*\(f\s?rom.*$\s?(.*)`

What this should do is:

1. Match anything up until 801.
2. Match anything until(f\s?rom
3. Match anything until $
4. Optional space
5. Match the rest of line line

The way I believe this breaks my string down is like so:

1. 801.
2. Our origination charge (Includes Originat ion Point (s) % or $ )
3. (f rom GRE #1
4. (nothing)
5. 1,169.00

However this is not the case. My regular expression does not match this string. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escape your dollar sign `$`. It's the end-of-line [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

```
.*801\..*\(f\s?rom.*\$\s?(.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.*801\..*\(f\s?rom.*\$\s?.*
```

Escape the $ character. And remove the brackets in the end.This regex exactly matches the string.

Comment: I assumed the parentheses were there intentionally as a capturing group, though that wasn't explicitly specified.